# Unkwon object in a file while writing from arraylist object

Tags: java, arraylist

```
try {
    File outFile = new File("C:/Users/USER/Desktop/Saumil/Saumil/output.datat");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);   
    oos.writeObject(list); // write list to ObjectOutputStream
                        
    oos.close();
    fos.close();
} catch(Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

The above code gives me such output shown below,whereas my input files has only integers in it.
Can anyone help me how to solve this problem

> ¬í sr java.util.ArrayListxÒ™Ça I sizexp   #w   #t
>
> 3  2345678910t 11  12345789t 18  1345678910t
>
> 39  235678910t
>
> 40  123678910t 42  12345678910t
>
> 48  123567910t 53  12345678910t 318

Answer (score 1):

Output generated by `writeObject()` is intended to be interpreted by the `readObject()` method of an `ObjectInputStream`, not by humans. If you want a human-readable file, try something like this instead:

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(outFile);
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fw);

for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
    out.write(list.get(i));
    out.newLine();
}
```

This will write the value of each element of `list` to a file instead of writing `list` itself to a file in a way that is not human-readable.

Answer (score 0):

Its correct only. In the above piece of code you are trying to serialize the list object. Although your list objects will have numbers but when you serialize that particular object in a file it put it in some binary form which is not readable. So don't worry,  when you deserialize it, you will get the exact same object you have stored previously!!!

Hope this answer will help you!!